# How to create excel list by smallest number excluding 0 (Zero values)

Tags: excel-formula, row, rounding

I'm generating a list in excel from an table of data and I want to exclude 0 from the results. The list is the players in a dart league with the fastest leg in a darts match.

I can do it using the following formula:

```
=SMALL(IF(PlayerTable[Fastest Leg]=0, "", PlayerTable[Fastest Leg]), ROWS('League Table'!$D$41:D41))
```

However, it doesn't pull in the name of the player that hit the fastest leg.

I have tried:

```
=SMALL((ROUND(PlayerTable[Fastest Leg],2)+ROW(PlayerTable[Fastest Leg])/10000),D41)
```

And in the cell to the left I have the formula:

```
=INDEX(PlayerTable[Player],MATCH('League Table'!G41,(ROUND(PlayerTable[Fastest Leg],2)+ROW(PlayerTable[Fastest Leg])/10000),0))
```

This looks at the number that has been pulled from the list and matches the players name.

However, with this formula it doesn’t ignore 0’s. That’s probably because the ROUND function gives each number a decimal.

Here's the table, The first column is used to give the 1st, 2nd, 3rd number (ranking). The second column the players name and the 4th column the lowest number of darts used to win a leg of darts.

[image]

How can I create a list of the lowest number ignoring 0 and also pull in the name of the player?

Comment: I'm not quite understanding. You wish to exclude all 0's but then again all the fastest legs of darts are actually 0? Can you elaborate on what your expected outcome is. Wouldn't you be looking for the MIN and IF combo?

Comment: Hi JvdV, 0's are only in the list because they haven't hit a fastest leg yet. We only record players that hit 15 darts or less in a leg. The fastest a player can finish a leg of 501 is in 9 darts. Also my formula pulls in the lowest number ignoring zero (actually anything  below 9) and then another formula adds the players name.

Comment: Also, I've tried MIN and IF, that works if I have a list of players names to reference but I then have to reorder and remove the players that haven't had a fastest leg yet and show a zero. =MIN(IF(FastestLeg[Player]=B3,IF(FastestLeg[[Home Fastest Leg]:[Away Fastest Leg]]<>0,FastestLeg[[Home Fastest Leg]:[Away Fastest Leg]])))